# Package Requires: libcurl.so.3

Tags: php, mysql, linux, centos, centos6

Mysql is not working with PHP. I got a blank white page on my website. and I'm looking for the problem, for some reasons, i found out that my php version doesn't have a mysql version. So look for some solutions and here's what I've gone so far.
I tried to update my php version and mysql.
I got this error after executing this command

```
yum install -y php php-mysql
```

i have a centOS 6.4 and a php 5.3.3 . and my php doesn't have a mysql support.  what should i do?
and after i execute the said command (yum install -y php php-mysql). I got an error message. Is there something wrong with my code?

```
Error: Package: php-common-5.3.27-2.w5.i386 (webtatic)  Requires: libcurl.so.3
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is strange as `yum` typically tries to resolve dependencies. Try installing libcurl manually:

```
yum install libcurl libcurl-devel
```

Comment: I still go the same error after doing your command and then yum install -y php php-mysql :( what to do? what to do? :(

Comment: Try installing package `curl` and re-trying.

Comment: Yes: `yum -i curl` and then `yum -i php-common`

Answer (score 3):

in my situation I solved my problem by enabling rpmforge-extras repository in yum.repos:

thanks to [this](https://community.hpcloud.com/question/875/centos-62-git-dependency-issues)

```
> cat /etc/yum.repos.d/rpmforge.repo 
...
[rpmforge-extras]
...
enabled = 0
```